# How to take two arrays in customAdapter class in a listview in android?

Tags: android

I am making a app toll free nos of India. But in this project there are so many arrays for listview, and when I am taking one array in java file then this code is working. But if I take two arrays in customAdapter class.

This code is not working.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;
    ArrayList2<DataModel> listArray2;
    Intent intent;
    int x;
    DataModel dataModel;

    public CustomAdapter() {

        if(x==0)
        {
            listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>(5);
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Air France", "", "1800-180-0033", ""));
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Air India","", "1800-180-1407", ""));
            listArray.add(new DataModel("American Airlines","", "1800-180-7300", ""));
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Austrian Airlines","", "1800-102-5838", ""));
            listArray.add(new DataModel("Aviations India","","1800-425-9898", ""));
            listArray.add(new DataModel("British Airways","", "1860-180-3592", ""));
        }

        if(x==1)
        {
            listArray2 = new ArrayList<DataModel>(6);
            listArray2.add(new DataModel("Ald Automotive", "", "1800-209-5253", ""));
            listArray2.add(new DataModel("Ashok Leyland","", "1800-266-3340", ""));
            listArray2.add(new DataModel("Audi","", "1800-103-6700", ""));
            listArray2.add(new DataModel("Autobahn Enterprises Pvt Ltd","", "1800-123-9009", ""));
            listArray2.add(new DataModel("Aviators India","", "1800-4257-7777", ""));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listArray.size();    // total number of elements in the list
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return listArray.get(i);    // single item in the list
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;                   // index number
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // if(x==0)
        // {
            dataModel = listArray.get(index);
        /* }else
        {
            dataModel = listArray2.get(index);
        }*/
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(dataModel.getName());

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setText("" + dataModel.getBlank());

        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setText("" + dataModel.getOtherData());

        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText("" + dataModel.getaDouble());
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows create another class file for Arraylist2...

Comment: Don't just copy paste everything you find. Try to learn, put some effort. You still don't understand even after seeing **Justin Jasmann** answer.

Comment: @user3432085 StackOverflow is not meant to solve your problems for you by writing the `full source code`, but rather help you figure out where you're going wrong. You should really read what a `class` is and how to use it properly, before attempting something like this. Here is a turotial :: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is a Java type. `ArrayList2` is not.

```
ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;
ArrayList2<DataModel> listArray2;
```

You probably just meant to leave it as `ArrayList`, unless you're intending on overriding the `List<E>` interface with a class named `ArrayList2`.

Comment: i can't understand what to do..provide me full source code??